# Im trying to make an animation trigger on roblox studio, can someone tell me how?

Tags: roblox

So when I try touch the trigger, the thing I'm trying to animate doesn't so the animation, I tried the  animation id, anything else, can someone send me a model that has this, it will be nice if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I made this with the gui elements already done u fill in what u need.

```
local library = {}

local function onClicked(frame, gui)
    gui:SetVisible(false)
    gui:ClearAllChildren()
end

function library:Create(parent)
    local frame = Instance.new("Frame")
    frame.Size = UDim2.new(1, 0, 1, 0)
    frame.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
    frame.BorderSizePixel = 0

    local gui = Instance.new("TextLabel")
    gui.Size = UDim2.new(0, 200, 0, 50)
    gui.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
    gui.Position = UDim2.new(0.5, -100, 0.5, -25)
    gui.Text = "Click the Button"
    gui.TextColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
    gui.TextXAlignment = Enum.TextXAlignment.Center
    gui.TextYAlignment = Enum.TextYAlignment.Center
    gui.Font = Enum.Font.SourceSans
    gui.TextSize = 24
    gui.Parent = frame

    local button = Instance.new("TextButton")
    button.Size = UDim2.new(0, 50, 0, 25)
    button.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(1, 0, 0)
    button.Position = UDim2.new(0.5, -25, 0.85, 0)
    button.Text = "X"
    button.TextColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
    button.Parent = frame

    button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        onClicked(frame, gui)
    end)

    frame.Parent = parent
    return frame
end
```

Comment: Is this a gui? if it is, I need something that triggers an humanoid to do an animation.